# htmlTable is replacing dataframe contents with sequential numbers

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

I'm using R markdown to create an html document. I've written a function that produces the following data frame as its output:

```
            April (&#36;) April Growth (&#37;) Current (&#36;) Current Growth (&#37;) Change (&#37;) 
1 2013:3    253,963.49                  0.2      251,771.20                    0.7            -0.9
2 2013:4    253,466.09                 -0.8      251,515.26                   -0.4            -0.8
3 2014:1    255,448.95                  3.2      255,300.10                    6.2            -0.1
4 2014:2    259,376.84                  6.3      259,919.99                    7.4             0.2
5 2014:3    261,398.85                  3.2      262,486.91                    4.0             0.4
6 2014:4    264,309.06                  4.5      266,662.59                    6.5             0.9
```

I'm then supplying this data frame to htmlTable as shown:

```
html.tab <- htmlTable(sample.df, rnames=F)       

print(html.tab)
```

However, when I knit the file I the following table is produced:

[image]

Can anyone explain what is happening? I thought perhaps it was the data class in the data frame but I didn't see anything in the htmlTable vignette saying it couldn't handle data of certain classes.
This is my first time working with R Markdown and htmlTables so hopefully I've just made some basic mistake but I haven't been able to find anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: By any chance are the columns in your database factors?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are. Is that the problem? Can htmlTable not work with factors?

Comment: I haven't used `htmlTable` enough to know for sure, but I would try using character strings instead of factors in `sample.df` and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Benjamin for the suggestion. It turns out the problem was the data class. sample.df contained data of class factor which apparently htmlTable can't handle. By converting the data to characters the correct table is produced.

```
sample.df[] <- lapply(sample.df, as.character)
```

Perhaps someone more familiar with the package can explain why factors are a problem?

I knew it would be something basic like this!